# Access Build Variable from Dockerfile on Azure Devops Build pipeline

Tags: variables, build, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to access a Azure Devops Build variable from a Dockerfile as a part of the build pipeline? Say I have a .NET core application and I have Azure Devops build pipeline where I have the usual build steps like .net restore, .net build. So if I have a step that reads like this dotnet publish -c Release -o $(Build.OutputDirectory), can I reference this $(Build.OutputDirectory) from my Dockerfile?

When build the image locally, I do a dotnet publish -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish and my dockerfile looks like so below:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

I am assuming that dockerfile for the Build pipeline should look like so below:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-**$(Build.OutputDirectory)**} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

Comment: Should you not just do the same in Azure Devops? As in, use the relative publish folder? Ideally, you don't want your docker file to be different across environments, surely? If you really would want this, I'd imagine you use some post processing on the docker file and replace, or pass build args into your Docker build command.

Comment: Where you able to find the solution?